# Tracking down an error from SPFX web part that started yesterday

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a Spfx web part used on a page in Sharepoint Online that's been in use for over a year. It hasn't changed in at least two months. It uses chart.js to display some data from an api call.

Suddenly, yesterday it started getting the error below. It's getting the same error whether it is on the live (production) site, my own personal SharePoint Online site, even when I add it to a page using "gulp serve". When I run it on my personal site, it's calling a different API server with different data, so I don't think it is data related. In fact, I don't even think it gets to the point where it calls the API.

```
Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
ERROR:
Script error for: 5c608aac-7f5e-49f8-8baa-f323b37b22d6_1.0.1/chart.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

CALL STACK:
Error: Script error for: 5c608aac-7f5e-49f8-8baa-f323b37b22d6_1.0.1/chart.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at B (eval at e (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_c8ac5e4cbe2ed48d1af54f3ada899ceb.js:68:369934), <anonymous>:8:252)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (eval at e (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_c8ac5e4cbe2ed48d1af54f3ada899ceb.js:68:369934), <anonymous>:30:244)
```

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Any ideas about what might be causing it, or tracking it down?

I even created a new Spfx web part from scratch that simply does a "var c = new Chart()" and it gets the same error. I tried using the latest version of chart.js and the same version in the original Spfx web part, no change.

This is the package.json that has been working for over a year:

```
{
  "name": "old-webpart",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/loader-set-webpack-public-path": "^4.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.14.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "@types/datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.16",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.12.1",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.12.1",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.2.0",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.4.0",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "^1.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.12.1-migrate"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9": "0.4.47",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.14.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

I rebuilt the web part using all of the latest SPFX packages, but it still doesn't work:

```
{
  "name": "new-webpart",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "@types/datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/datatables.net-select": "^1.2.7",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.16",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.12.1",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.12.1",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup": "^1.2.0",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.4.0",
    "datatables.net-select-dt": "1.4.0 --save",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.5": "0.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.17.0-beta.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.5"
  }
}
```

The imports are:

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
import { IReadonlyTheme } from '@microsoft/sp-component-base';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';

import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-select';
import 'datatables.net-rowgroup';
import 'datatables.net-buttons';

import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

import * as strings from 'NewTestWebPartStrings';
```

As you can see I also use datatables.net. I left these in, but reduced the webpart down to:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    //@ts-ignore
    let ch = new Chart();

    return;
 } );
```

If I comment out:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

let ch = new Chart();
```

There are no errors. I have render() with simply this, and I see "Hello":

```
 public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
</body>
 `;
```

Comment: show your package.js and the relevant portion of the code (including the imports). Remove all the API stuff and hard code the data.

Comment: Maybe issue with version mismatch of libraries used in web part.

Comment: I have included my package json from the original webpart, and from the rebuilt webpart. I removed all api code and posted the imports and reduced the ready() function to simply creating the chart.

Comment: Some additional info... in the Chrome debug console, I am seeing this error: Refused to execute script from 'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/b35349c7-a32a-4732-a3d2-e9cae34c7412_0.0.1/chart.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: As you are saying everything was working fine and suddenly it stopped working so maybe something latest in SharePoint online is causing issue with Chart.js. you can submit the issue on https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues

Comment: @HarminderSingh Yes, it was working fine for about a year. I have resolved it, but I am not really sure why it occurred. (I hate that.) I had "chart.js" and a reference to the CDN for it at cdnjd.cloudflare.com in the config.json "externals". I removed it from there and rebuilt the webpart and it worked. I considered that there was some issue with the cloudflare CDN, but (I think) I tried another CDN with the same results.  And I am getting jquery from the cloudflare CDN with no problem (still). And it was a server side error, so I don't know why it would even know about it.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: @RaytheonXie-MSFT See my comment above. I removed the external reference to chart.js and it worked again. I don't know why, and I am getting jquery from the same CDN, and it had no problem getting chart.js from that CDN... up until March 2, 2023.